# Decoding a bitmask from a value in C#

Tags: c#, bit, bitmask, bitflags

I am trying to decode a bitmask

```
[Flags]
public enum Amenities
{
    BusinessCenter = 1,
    FitnessCenter = 2,
    HotTub = 4,
    InternetAccess = 8,
    KidsActivities = 16,
    Kitchen = 32,
    PetsAllowed = 64,
    Pool = 128,
    Restaurant = 256,
    Spa = 512,
    Whirlpool = 1024,
    Breakfast = 2048,
    Babysitting = 4096,
    Jacuzzi = 8192,
    Parking = 16384,
    RoomService = 32768,
    AccessibleTravel = 65536,
    AccessibleBathroom = 131072,
    RollShower = 262144,
    HandicappedParking = 524288,
    InRoomAccessibility = 1048576,
    AccessibilityDeaf = 2097152,
    BrailleSignage = 4194304,
    FreeAirportShuttle = 8388608,
    IndoorPool =  16777216,
    OutdoorPool = 33554432,
    ExtendedParking = 67108864,
    FreeParking = 134217728
}
```

How do I write a function that decodes a value like 5722635 and returns a list of all Amenities that are encoded in 5722635.

the result should look like this:

This Property has the following Amenities:

- Business Center
- Fitness Center
- Internet Access
- Available Spa On-site
- Babysitting
- Parking
- Accessible Path of Travel
- Accessible Bathroom
- Roll-in Shower
- In-room Accessibility
- Braille or Raised Signage

I have been trying things like

```
public List<Amenities> Decode(long mask)
        {
            var list = new List<Amenities>();
            for (var index = 0; index < 16; index++)
            {
                var bit = 1 << index;
                if (0 != (bit & mask))
                {
                    list.Add(new Amenities(index));
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
```

But can not get it to work.
Any suggestions on how to make this work properly would be appreciated.

Comment: 16 isn't enough and that `new` syntax to cast probably doesn't work

Comment: the new syntax definitely does not work. You cannot create a 'new' instance of an enum member like that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about one-liner?

```
var mask = (Amenities)5722635;

var result =
    Enum.GetValues(typeof(Amenities))
        .Cast<Amenities>()
        .Where(value => mask.HasFlag(value))
        .ToList();
```

You can cache result of `Enum.GetValues(typeof(Amenities)).Cast<Amenities>()` in order to improve performance.

Comment: This simple solution did get the job done... thanx pwas

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, your method is taking in a `long`, yet your enum implicitly uses an `int` as the underlying data type. Either store the value as an `int` or change the underlying data type in your enum to a `long`: `[Flags] public enum Amenities : long { ... }`

Secondly, if your enum is marked with the `FlagsAttribute` you really don't need to turn the value into an list of values, you can use the `Enum.HasFlag()` method to check for a flagged value. You'll have to cast your long into an `Amenities` type first:

```
var amenities = (Amenities)mask;

if (amentities.HasFlag(Amenities.BusinessCenter)) { ... }
```

---

But, if you really want to split that flag into a list of amenities instead:

```
public IList<Amenities> Decode(long mask)
{
        var amenities = (Amenities)mask;
        var list = new List<Amenities>();

        foreach (Amenities amenity in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Amenities))
        {
            if (amenities.HasFlag(amenity))
                list.Add(amenity);
        }

        return list;
}
```

Comment: This also works very well and follows the initial idea I was after. Thank you m-y